# sudo: xhost: command not found

Tags: linux, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to solve the following error on Google Colab. Gtk-WARNING **: 11:06:40.546: cannot open display:
So I ran the below command:

```
!sudo xhost +export DISPLAY=:1
```

But it's showing the error below:

```
sudo: xhost: command not found
```

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general linux usage issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Question is obviously about `google-colaboratory`, and it has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).